# Multiple "My Documents" folders?

Tags: windows-7, shell, windows-registry, start-menu, folder-redirection

I am having the issue, where, I have 2 folders called "My Documents". I recently edited my registry to make "Document" link in the Windows 7 start menu be a **FOLDER** link and not a **LIBRARY** link..

Here is the Registry Key information for the Documents key:

```
Key Name:          HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{7b0db17d-9cd2-4a93-9733-46cc89022e7c}
Class Name:        <NO CLASS>
Last Write Time:   3/2/2011 - 2:33 AM
Value 0
  Name:            Attributes
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1

Value 1
  Name:            Category
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x4

Value 2
  Name:            Icon
  Type:            REG_EXPAND_SZ
  Data:            %SystemRoot%\system32\imageres.dll,-1002

Value 3
  Name:            LocalizedName
  Type:            REG_EXPAND_SZ
  Data:            @%SystemRoot%\system32\shell32.dll,-34575

Value 4
  Name:            Name
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            Documents

Value 5
  Name:            PublishExpandPath
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1

Value 6
  Name:            PrecCreate
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1

Value 7
  Name:            RelativePath
  Type:            REG_SZ
  Data:            Documents

Value 8
  Name:            Roamable
  Type:            REG_DWORD
  Data:            0x1
```

Also, Navigating through computer to "C:\Users\Flasimbufasa\"
Only shows one folder called "Documents"

However, whenever I navigate to user profile from "Desktop\Flasimbufasa"
I get 2 Document folders.

Any help?

Comment: If you change it back to the way it was originally, does it work?

Comment: Yes, there is only one folder when I revert back to using [or lack of] the libraries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Revert changes and apply these:

http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/92587-start-menu-user-folder-buttons-open-users-instead-libraries.html